# Script deleting itself

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like that :

```
<body>
<script id="a" >
//Here i do a lot of things, then
document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById("a"));
</script>
</body>
```

And it's not working !

Comment: Define "not working". Do you want the script to be removed from view-source?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. Why do you want the script removed anyway? By looking at the browser source it will still be there, as it will have been rendered. Theoretically, it will just be removed from memory, but again, not sure if you can do this, especially from itself.

Comment: If you expect it to disappear from "View Page Source": That is not possible. But it gets removed from the DOM. Check in firebug or a similar tool, it works for me.

Comment: I know I can't remove it from the "view source". I just want to remove it from memory (and of course from firebug).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe trying to delete the script from itself is causing issues. Maybe this will work ...

```
<script id="a">
    var stuffFinished = false;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //do your stuff here
        stuffFinished = true;
    });
</script> 

<script id="b">
    $(document).ready(function(){
       var timer = setInterval(function() {
         if (stuffFinished) {
           $("#a").remove();
           clearTimeout(timer);
         }
       }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

I've not tested this, just an idea ...

Comment: Can you give me a way without jQuery ?

Comment: I can tell you how. Use the onload event in the body tag to fire both methods for example <body onload="scriptA(); scriptB();">, then instead of the wrapping the code in a jquery function, just wrap it in your own functions ie function scriptA() { // your code here }. Does this help?

Comment: oh, and you will need to make the timer var a global - stick it outside the function decleration

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, depending on where you are inserting the script, the browser might execute the code before it has even **finished creating the DOM**.
It would be better to use a framework like jQuery and wait for the document to finish loading, before executing the code. If you'd use jquery, it would work like this:

```
<script id="a">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //do your stuff here

       $("#a").remove();
    });
</script>
```